# Where to put manually compiled binaries?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, software-compilation

I manually built the latest version of BlueZ (5.50) and I need to access some tools from Python. Where is the recommended location to put compiled binaries so that they are accessible for all users?

I am running Raspbian Stretch 9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `/usr/local/bin` (and friends) or `/opt/<package name here>/bin/`. The latter has the downside people had to manually add the directory to their search paths.